# -webkit-transform suddently added to List elements in Sencha Touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I upgraded from Sencha Touch 2.0.1 to 2.1 and suddently the framework adds a -webkit-transform to all my list elements which destroys lot of my layout, anyone knows why it does so and how to remove it?

See attachement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Sencha Touch 2.1 the list component was completly redesigned.

**Quote from Realease notes:**

*The new List component is included with this release. This implementation replaces the old one for lists and is no longer bound one-to-one between a store and DOM elements. This means that the length of the list will no longer have a bearing on it's scrolling performance. In addition, lists can use components if you specify them with an itemConfig and itemTpl will be converted to an itemConfig dynamically if you specify one. Due to these changes, the DOM structure was altered for lists and you may need to change some css selectors to add appropriate styling for your lists. Typically you need to change the selector from '.x-list-item' to '.x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body' for any padding or margins you may have added. We have change the TouchTweets example from using a component based DataView to the new List very easily and should be a good example of using the new List component with dynamic large lists.*

http://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-coming-in-sencha-touch-2-1

The redesign is the reason for the new css list elements.

I think you have to change and customize your css again for your list.

Comment: See see, thanks. I also see now that I used List semantically incorrect some places, in the attachement I added I see its better to use DataView